# Magento 2 category attribute select

Tags: magento2

i tried to create custom category attribute with custom source class, but select input has no options. I dont know why, i am missing something. I checked and attribute exists in database. Thank you for help.

UpgradeData.php

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.1.3') < 0) {
        $categorySetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $categorySetup->addAttribute(Category::ENTITY, 'category_heroslider', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Category Hero Slider',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => xxx\xxx\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\HeroSlider::class,
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
            'user_defined' => true,
            'visible' => true,
        ]);
    }
```

source class

```
namespace xxx\xxx\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class xxx extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @var \xxx\xxx\Model\ResourceModel\Slider\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $slidersCollection;

    /**
     * HeroSlider constructor.
     * @param \xxx\xxxx\Model\ResourceModel\Slider\CollectionFactory $slidersCollection
     */
    public function __construct(\xxx\xxx\Model\ResourceModel\Slider\CollectionFactory $slidersCollection)
    {
        $this->slidersCollection = $slidersCollection;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $this->_options = [
            ['label' => __('Yes'), 'value' => 1],
            ['label' => __('asd'), 'value' => 2],
        ];

        return $this->_options;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [1 => 'test'];
    }


}
```

category_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="general">
    <field name="category_heroslider">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">xxx\xxx\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\HeroSlider</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Hero Slider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your source model to implements

```
Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution with detailed description?

Comment: @RahulSharma I mean this class
`xxx\xxx\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\HeroSlider ` need to implements `Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface`

Comment: Please update your answer with what you have mentioned in comment and also follow the posting guidelines for writing well formed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).